# Java Socket UDP Loop

Tags: java, sockets, loops, tcp, udp

I am trying to set up a program that looks into UDP performance of packets and response times on my network. I have a client and server side class, for which I am specifying the packet size which to send pieces of text. For example, if I want to send a word of "Tester" in a 4 byte packet, it will send the "TEST" part but not reiterate through the rest of the word. I have tried to add in a while loop, but i don't think what I have is correct as it continuously sends the first 4 bytes. Does anyone know what sort of loop I need and where abouts it should be placed to get the outcome I am after? Code for the client is below. Many thanks in advance for any guidance.

```
//UDP Client
//Usage: java UDPClient [server addr] [server port]

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class UDPClient extends variable {

   // static Integer portNo = 4444;
    static Integer byteSize = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      SocketForm form = new SocketForm();

      long startTime; // Starting time of program, in milliseconds.
      long endTime;   // Time when computations are done, in milliseconds.
      double time;  

        //get server address
        String serverName = "localhost";

        if (args.length >= 1)
            serverName = args[0];
      InetAddress serverIPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverName);

        //get server port;
        int serverPort = form.cliportNo;
        if (args.length >= 2)
            serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        //create socket
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        //get input from keybaord
        byte[] sendData = new byte[byteSize];
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        while (true){ //incorrect as it is only repeating the first four bytes of the word typed in the console
        String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        sendData = sentence.getBytes();
        //construct and send datagram;

        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, serverIPAddress, serverPort);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

        //receive datagram
        byte[] receiveData = new byte [byteSize];

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        //print output
        String sentenceFromServer = new String(receivePacket.getData());
        System.out.println("From Server:" + sentenceFromServer);

        //close client socket
                //clientSocket.close();
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        time = endTime - startTime;
        //System.out.println("Time :" + time);
        }
    } //end of main
} //end of UDPClient
```

Comment: If you chop your payload into peaces, you have to reconstruct it yourself. Remember that UDP Packets can come in out of order or not all ... Is this some kind of assignment?

Comment: Its sort of an assignment. Its something the boss has tasked us with as he is 'interested' in that sort of stuff. (I'm new to the Java team and its been a while since I worked with it) Ideally we are just looking to see that our program is able to break up a string, fit the bytes into a set packet size, and time how long those packets take to be transmitted. Im not so bothered about the reconstruction, just the time each packet will take to transmit. Is there a way to say 'send the first 4 bytes of this string', loop through and send the next four until there are no bytes left to transmit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
private void sendChunked( String msg, int chunkSizeInBytes ) {
   byte[] msgBytes = msg.getBytes();
   for( int index = 0; index < msgBytes.length ; index += chunkSizeInBytes ) {
         DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( msgBytes, index, Math.min( chunkSizeInBytes, msgBytes.length-index ));
         send( packet ); // You know how that works ...
   }
}
```